# Using Bash, how can I replace characters in this variable in one location, but not another?

Tags: bash

Here's an example of my bash script and the output I currently get:

**bash.sh**

```
echo "$INSTANCE_IP ip-$INSTANCE_IP.hostname.com" | tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Here's what get's added to my **/etc/hosts** file:

```
10.0.2.110 ip-10.0.2.110.hostname.com
```

I would like to replace the `.` characters with `-`, but only in the domain name portion. So when it first passes in my variable `$INSTANCE_IP` I need it to be the actual IP address so the `.`'s need to be included and the domain name needs to have my IP address but with `-` instead.

So here's my desired output in my **/etc/hosts** file

```
10.0.2.110 ip-10-0-2-110.hostname.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use substitution on 2nd instance of variable like this:

```bash
echo "$INSTANCE_IP ip-${INSTANCE_IP//./-}.hostname.com"
```